# removeAttr("href") on anchor also removed text color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have a web site that uses JQuery and JQuery UI.

For some links, I didn't want to use JQuery UI Theme's colors, so I overrided using my own css.

It all worked until I used `$("#a_about").removeAttr("href")` to remove the href from the anchors (so that the link wouldn't actually work, I just want to grab the click action)
to my surprise, it also removed the color which my css applied, and returned to the color which JQuery UI Theme applied previously.

I tried to change the element on which the color is applied (the anchor itself, the parent container, etc...) but nothing helped.
Thanks...

Comment: can you post some html code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$("#a_about").removeAttr("href")
```

Use:

```
$("#a_about").attr("href","javascript:;")
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because on some browser, a anchor `a` without attribute `href` is treat as normal text. So try change the `href` to `javascript:;` instead of remove it.

Comment: This will scroll back to the top of the page.

Comment: I think we're trying to fix the problem of `changing the text color`?

Comment: I would assume that a fix for one problem that introduced a different problem would be undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

Anchor without `href` is not really a link. As others said set it to something like `#` and to "cancel" the click, also have:

```
$("#a_about").attr("href", "#").click(function() { return false; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't touch the href. [Prevent the default action](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in the event handler instead.

This way the link will continue to work if people, for example, middle click on it.

Comment: But maybe he don't want people to think it leads to somewhere when it's not?

Comment: It does lead somewhere, if it didn't, it wouldn't have an href in the first place.

Comment: I don't want the middle click to work. I needed to have the href there for SEO, but in reality I show the same content in a dialog which is opened.

Comment: Breaking user expectations is generally a bad idea, if the user wants to read the content in a new tab, why stop them?